# ImageMagick + Cocoa app in one bundle

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, app-store, imagemagick

OK, what I'm trying to do is fairly straightforward, although I definitely have no idea how to proceed :

- I have created an Objective-C wrapper for ImageMagick functions
- I want to embed ImageMagick *inside* the app bundle, so that the app works on no-matter-which OS X version (10.6,10.7,10,8)

Any ideas? How would you go about it?

---

**P.S.** Of course, we'll take for granted that the user will **not** have ImageMagick already installed - so all should loaded from our app bundle.

Comment: Go about what?  We don't even know how your wrapper or whatever works.

Answer (score 2):

We know nothing about your wrapper.

- you want execute bundled ImageMagick commands (as standalone command-line tools, like `convert` `mogrify`)? If so, check this question and answers

  - [How can I make a GUI frontend to a command line tool in OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592479/how-can-i-make-a-gui-frontend-to-a-command-line-tool-in-osx)
- Your wrapper uses ImageMagick as a library?, in this case you should read:

  - [How do third-party libraries work in Objective-C and Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250302/how-do-third-party-libraries-work-in-objective-c-and-xcode)
  - [Trying to embed dynamic libraries along with C++ Xcode project, but they're not getting properly referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462702/trying-to-embed-dynamic-libraries-along-with-c-xcode-project-but-theyre-not)
  - [How to include a third party binary in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524088/how-to-include-a-third-party-binary-in-xcode)
  - [Bundle framework with application in XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621451/bundle-framework-with-application-in-xcode)
- and many others like above on the google.

In any case - it looks as an duplicate... ;)

Comment: I want to execute bundled ImageMagick commands. In any case, the answer you point me to is **not** helpful at all. I *do* know how to make a frontend to a OSX Console command - **IF** it's already there (= pre-installed). My question revolves around *how* to put a working ImageMagick "installation" in the app bundle, so that there are no unresolved dependencies and that the user doesn't have to install anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you're looking for are instructions for building a static library for OS X?
http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=13145&p=44175&hilit=static+Mac#p44175

Given that we don't know anything about your wrapper, it is hard to give advice beyond this.